# eq_join like functionality on a single object

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I have 2 tables child and parent:

```
child
    {id:1, parent_id: 10, name:"blah" ...}

parent
    {id:10, name: "parent blah" ....}
```

I know the id of the child object and want to query the child object joined with the parent object.

Is there a way i can do the equivalent of :

```
r.table('child').get(10).eq_join('parent_id', r.table('parent'))
```

eq_joins work great on the results of a filter operation since it returns a sequence. I want to perform a similar operation when i use get

so an eq_join of the form:

```
r.table('child').filter({'id': 1}).eq_join('parent_id', r.table('parent'))
```

gives me records

```
{left: {id: 10, parent_id:1, ...},
right: {id:1, ....}}
```

which works great for a sequence.

I want to carry out the same operations in a case where I use a get instead of filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that (in Python)

```
r.table('child').get(10).merge(lambda child:
    {
        'parent': r.table('parents').get(child['parent_id'])
    }
)
```

If you want exactly the same output as with `eq_join`, you can do

```
r.expr([r.table('child').get(10)]).eq_join('parent_id', r.table('parent'))
```

Comment: The merge approach is exactly what I needed! I just did not know how i could access the child in merge. Thanks a lot